# Excel - Finding adjacent cells that equal a certain value

Tags: excel, vba, function, macros

I have an issue in Excel where I need to find if two adjacent cells are both equal to 100. I need some way to change a cells value to true or false based on this condition. Here is an example data set

```
   A1: 100
   A2: 95
   A3: 84
   A4: 100
   A5: 100
   A6: 86
   A7: 92
```

In this case, I would want the result to be true because A4 and A5 are adjacent *and* both contain 100.

The only helpful thing I have found online is this function but it doesn't get me all the way there.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B5)>1,1,0)
```

Would I be better off coming up with a macro?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use countifs with set ranges that are shifted one cell down:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,B5,A2:A101,B5)>0
```

[image]